# Get delimiter from a long string to split

Tags: c#

There are long strings which are delimiter separated. the delimiter can be changed but there are some fixed set. I want to extract the delimiter to perform the split operation.

```
String  sLongName = "abc1234646;dfsdfsdfsdf44654654;asdfsdsdf;sadfsdfs446";
```

The set of delimiters are `{";" "," "/" "$"}`.

So how can i get the delimiter at runtime which one is used among the above set to separate the string

Comment: Can't you just use them all? `sLongName.Split(new string[] { ";", ",", "/", "$"});`

Comment: i can but as of now the list is small if it increases will it create any performance impact...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean to find which one of the delimiters appears in the string?

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] { ';', ',', '/', '$' };
char? usedDelimiter = delimiters.FirstOrDefault(d => sLongName.IndexOf(d) != -1);
```

Assuming that the string contains just one (or none) of the delimiter characters, you could subsequently split using:

```
string[] splitString;
if (usedDelimiter != null)
    splitString = sLongName.Split(usedDelimiter.Value);
else
    splitString = new string[] { sLongName };
```

Comment: If OP's concern is performance, this has *worse* performance than just calling split on all valid delimiters! They are both `O(n)` but this has a worse constant!

Comment: @Jason: That depends on whether there is a bias in the frequency with which the respective delimiters are used. If, say, `;` is used as the delimiter in 90% of the strings, then the above will likely perform faster in the average case. (Yes, this is a laboured justification; my point is that the question didn't really give any information about the performance requirements.)

Comment: The comment wasn't directed at you; your answer is good. It was directed at the OP since he brought up performance as a concern in his comments.

Comment: Fair enough. I agree that this feels like a case of premature optimization (unless the OP is dealing with massive strings or delimiter sets).

Comment: thanks Douglas and Jason for your response after carefully measuring the performance in most of the cases the delimiter would be ";" and "," , so it will work perfectly for my cases

Answer (score 2):

You can split on all of the delimiters:

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] { ';',',','/','$' };
string[] parts = value.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you can't just split on all of them?

```
var fields = sLongName.Split(new string[] { ";", ",", "/", "$"});
```

Comment: i have posted an comment for same.

Comment: @ankur: Performance? Non-issue, almost surely. And don't guess. Measure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the delimiters are never used inside the "normal" text, you could

```
Char[] dels = new Char [] {';', ',', '/', '$'};
Char del='\0';
foreach (Char c in dels)
   if (sLongName.IndexOf(c)>=0)
   {
      del=c;
      break;
   }
if (del=='\0') throw new InvalidOperationException("I'm afraid, I can't do this, Chris!");
//del is now your delimiter.
```